# Why useState doesn't work after fetching data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

when I console.log my response from api, it's there. But then when I try to set state via the usestate hook, it doesn't update state.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const getLocation = () => {
axios
  .get(
    `https://myrequest=${
      process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE
    }&address=${location}`
  )
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response) //response is present
    setData(response)
    console.log(data)// data didn't update,empty array
  })
```

};
//getLocation is called by a button with onClick

Comment: I'm still a little new to javascript, how can rewrite my function asynchronously, i thought the promise was taking care of  the synchronous stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working, but `data` will not update synchronously by calling `setData`, and `data` is still a reference to the old array.

Try to render `data` and you will see that it updates correctly.

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function getData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(['foo', 'bar'])
    }, 1000)
  })
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  function getLocation() {
    getData().then(response => {
      setData(response)
      console.log(data)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(item => (
        <div key={item}>{item}</div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={getLocation}>Load location</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```